# How to count how many times user amend orders based on PreviousOrderID or/and NextOrderID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to get count how many times user/client amend the order based on orderID, PreviousOrderID and NextOrderID

```
select 
    OrderID, OrderDate, ClientID, OrderStatus,
    BuySell, Price, Qty, PrevOrderID, NextOrderID 
from 
    [History_Order_Trx] 
where 
    OrderDate = @date
    and PrevOrderID >= 1 OR OrderDate = @date
    and NextOrderID >=1
order by 
    ClientID, OrderID
```

Sample data:

```
OrderID OrderDate   ClientID    OrderStatus BuySell Price   Qty     PrevOrderID NextOrderID 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
07     7/9/2019     20441       A           S       1400    11800   -1          20
20     7/9/2019     20441       O           S       1230    11800   07          00
45     7/9/2019     20538       A           S       1240    10000   -1          51
51     7/9/2019     20538       A           S       1230    10000   45          80
80     7/9/2019     20538       O           S       1220    10000   51          00
```

Result:

```
clientid    totalAmend 
----------------------
   20441       1
   20538       2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  select clientid ,case when max(rn-1) = 0 then 1 else max(rn-1) end as totalAmend from (
select *,row_number over (partition by clientid order by Orderdate),rn from [History_Order_Trx]
) t
group by clientid
```

Answer (score 0):

Your OR condition in the WHERE statement has issue. You need to write the WHERE as below to meet any part of filtering condition TRUE to return data.

```
SELECT  
OrderID,OrderDate,ClientID,OrderStatus,BuySell,
Price,Qty,PrevOrderID,NextOrderID 
FROM [History_Order_Trx] 
WHERE 
(
    OrderDate = @date
    AND PrevOrderID >= 1 
)
OR 
(
    OrderDate = @date
    AND NextOrderID >=1
)
ORDER BY ClientID,OrderID
```